# TableView automatic dimension

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have set the auto dimension of the label but whenever data is loaded in table view it expand to 10 lines however text is about 1 line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zUJ6.png)

[Thats the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naxq2.png)

Comment: Please add code directly, same with image.
Regarding the question, it really looks like the big cell with one line of text is being set to height = 350. You should check your code for setting this flag. It would also be good to have this flag be a boolean instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that picFlag is = "0" or not in response and make sure you have implemented estimatedHeightForRow delegate